# Value for Input Options

Tags: node.js, body-parser

Need assistance on how to get the value of input options:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Color</label>
        </div>
        <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
          <option selected>Choose...</option>
          <option value="1" >Blue</option>
          <option value="2">Green</option>
          <option value="3">Yellow</option>
          <option value="4">Orange</option>
          <option value="5">Red</option>
        </select>
      </div>

My model is like this:

        User.register({
            fname: req.body.firstname,
            lname: req.body.lastname,
            nickname: req.body.nickname,
            email: req.body.email,
            color: req.body.value,
            designation: req.body.designation,
            username: req.body.username,
```

I can't get the value for the chosen options, appreciate for any assistance. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

To communicate between your frontend and backend you'll have to setup a route and make an HTTP request. I'd suggest using [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

To get the inputs value you could do:

```
const inputValue = document.getElementById('inputGroupSelect01').value;
```

Then with Axios:

```
async sendInputValue() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:5000/'

    await Axios.post(`${url}register`, inputValue)
        .then(res => {
            // Do whatever on success
        }).catch(err => {
            // Do whatever with error
        }
}
```

Then, on your backend:

```
router.post('register', (req, res) => {
   // Use it however you want
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is how you mean, but it should point you in the right direction at least.

Comment: Hi @Daniel_Knights, thank you for taking time to give response on my question. Really Appreciate it. I was able to solve the question when I wrote name = "", on the select. Have a great day!